# How to read the data from the JSON stringifyed array of objects and loop through it and use the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I'm using Node JS packages and below is the help I want

I have the following JSON data.

```
[{
"name":"IronMan",
"description":"Genius",
"head_id":"34",
"domain_name":"ironman.com"
}]
```

I want to access the Value of the keys inside a loop. I don't know how to loop through the above JSON data.

Comment: Using `Node`?  or simply `JS`?

Answer (score 2):

```
const parsedData= JSON.parse(data) // This will parse your stringifyed Array of objects

parsedData.forEach(entry=> {
// looping through each object in the array and accessing its keys using Object.values()
  Object.values(entry).forEach(value=> {
     console.log(value) // here you will get all the values of all the objects in an d 
  })
})


// You can also use 
Object.keys(entry).forEach(key => {
// key = 'name'
    console.log(entry[key]))
}
// You can also use 
Object.entries(entry).forEach(keyValuePair =>{
 // keyValuePair = ['name', 'IronMan']
  console.log('key', keyValuePair[0])
  console.log('value', keyValuePair[1])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn about the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop then.

```js
let stuff=[{
"name":"IronMan",
"description":"Genius",
"head_id":"34",
"domain_name":"ironman.com"
}];

for(let item of stuff) // this is not the one, just example data is an array
  for(let key in item) // this is the one
    console.log(key,item[key]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Even this helped and produced the same output. :) :D